# Index of tensor product of two Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products

Let $S$ and $T$ Fredholm operators on a separable complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ such that the tensor product $S\otimes T$ is also a Fredholm operator on $\mathcal H\otimes\mathcal H$. So what to say about the index:
$$
j(S\otimes T)=?
$$ 
Remember that $j(T)=\operatorname{dim}(\ker(T))-\operatorname{dim}(\ker(T^{*}))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the finite-dimensional setting, every operator is Fredholm with index zero.  So let's assume $\mathcal H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Firstly, note that if $x\in\ker(T)$ is non-trivial, then $x\otimes y\in\ker(T\otimes S)$ for any $y\in\mathcal H$.  Thus $\ker(T\otimes S)$ is infinite-dimensional as long as either $\ker(T)$ or $\ker(S)$ is non-trivial, and therefore $T\otimes S$ is not Fredholm.  Similarly, we see that if $\ker(T^*)$ or $\ker(S^*)$ is non-trivial, then $T\otimes S$ is not Fredholm.  Thus the only time that $T\otimes S$ is Fredholm is when $T$ and $S$ are both invertible, in which case $T\otimes S$ is invertible, and the index of all three operators is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help!